# What does OBF mean in the context of linear programming?

Tags: terminology, linear-programming

> Hence the rate of change of the OBF value with respect to the RHS going down.

I could find OBFS which means *Optimal Basic Feasible Solution*, but not OBF. I could find some references to the term [here](https://books.google.be/books?id=fr3w56xbzikC&pg=PA317&lpg=PA317&dq=OBF%20linear%20programming&source=bl&ots=F30oGA77d-&sig=L70a-BA3pzD0SdOVFm8jC7-DOSU&hl=nl&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwimvsaojNPbAhUCEywKHUgOAn4Q6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=OBF%20linear%20programming&f=false), but no explanation.

Comment: Where does that sentence come from? What is the source?

Comment: Maybe it means $\textbf{OB}\text{jective} \  \textbf{F}\text{unction}$ in this context.